# tcpclient webrelay and control analog outputs

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient

This is the first time that I have ever worked with networking in a program control webrelay. I was able to write my program with success... or so I thought. A couple of days ago I had a device drop off the network and my program "locked up". I know it did not truly lock up. I did some debugging and found out that what is happening is that when the tcpclient throws an exception, it just stops running any code after it. This causes my program to stop updating because of a timer that is never restarted and I con't control analog Outputs.

```
Public Class ControlPanelX317
Private SQL As New SQLControl

Private Sub ControlPanelX317_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    LoadControlsX317()
End Sub
'Dislay Conrol
'__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Private Sub LoadControlsX317()
    Dim loadqry As String = "SELECT * FROM controlsX317  WHERE controlsX317.ValueVoltageID = '" & 1 & "' "
    Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand(loadqry, Sql.SQLCon)

    If Sql.SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then Sql.SQLCon.Open()

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
    While reader.Read = True
        txt_S1_VolueVoltage.Text = reader("S1VolueVoltage")
        txt_S2_VolueVoltage.Text = reader("S2VolueVoltage")
        txt_S3_VolueVoltage.Text = reader("S3VolueVoltage")
        txt_S4_VolueVoltage.Text = reader("S4VolueVoltage")

    End While
    SQLCmd.Dispose()
    reader.Close()
    Sql.SQLCon.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub btn_Save_ValueVoltage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Save_ValueVoltage.Click
    If txt_S1_VolueVoltage.Text > 10 Then
        MsgBox("Max Voltage is 10V")
        txt_S1_VolueVoltage.Clear()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If txt_S2_VolueVoltage.Text > 10 Then
        MsgBox("Max Voltage is 10V")
        txt_S2_VolueVoltage.Clear()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If txt_S3_VolueVoltage.Text > 10 Then
        MsgBox("Max Voltage is 10V")
        txt_S3_VolueVoltage.Clear()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If txt_S4_VolueVoltage.Text > 10 Then
        MsgBox("Max Voltage is 10V")
        txt_S4_VolueVoltage.Clear()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If txt_S1_VolueVoltage.Text <> "" Then
        Dim UpdateValueVoltage As String = "UPDATE controlsX317 SET S1VolueVoltage='" & txt_S1_VolueVoltage.Text & "',  S2VolueVoltage='" & txt_S2_VolueVoltage.Text & "',
                                          S3VolueVoltage='" & txt_S3_VolueVoltage.Text & "', S4VolueVoltage='" & txt_S4_VolueVoltage.Text & "' 
                                          WHERE ValueVoltageID ='" & 1 & "' "
        If SQL.DataUpdate(UpdateValueVoltage) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("The Sysytem could not be found!!! ")
        Else
            MsgBox("VolueVoltage successfully changed")
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox("You must restart a Sysytem")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn_S1_SetVoltage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_S1_SetVoltage.Click
    lbl_S1_AnalogOutput.Text = Val(txt_S1_VolueVoltage.Text) * Val(txt_S1_ControlViltage.Text / 100) & "V"
End Sub

Private Sub btn_S2_SetVoltage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_S2_SetVoltage.Click
    lbl_S2_AnalogOutput.Text = Val(txt_S2_VolueVoltage.Text) * Val(txt_S2_ControlViltage.Text / 100) & "V"
End Sub

Private Sub btn_S3_SetVoltage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_S3_SetVoltage.Click
    lbl_S3_AnalogOutput.Text = Val(txt_S3_VolueVoltage.Text) * Val(txt_S3_ControlViltage.Text / 100) & "V"
End Sub

Private Sub btn_S4_SetVoltage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_S4_SetVoltage.Click
    lbl_S4_AnalogOutput.Text = Val(txt_S4_VolueVoltage.Text) * Val(txt_S4_ControlViltage.Text / 100) & "V"
End Sub
'End Display Control
'_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

'Conection to WebRelay X317
'_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Public Sub getWebRelayState()
    Dim tcpClient As New TcpClient()
    Dim port As Integer

    Try
        port = Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text)
        tcpClient.Connect(txt_IPAddress.Text, port)

        If tcpClient.Connected Then


            'Create a network stream object
            Dim netStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()

            'If we can read and write to the stream then do so
            If netStream.CanWrite And netStream.CanRead Then

                'Send the on command to webrelay
                Dim sendBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET /state.xml?noReply=0 HTTP/1.1" & vbCrLf & "Authorization: Basic bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ==" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
                netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

                'Get the response from webrelay
                Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
                netStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))

                'Parse the response and update the webrelay state and input text boxes
                Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)

                'Parse out the relay state and input state
                Dim array1 As Char() = returndata.ToCharArray()

                Dim ana(4) As Integer

                'Relay State found at index 66
                If array1(66) = "1" Then
                    RelayState.Text = "ON"
                Else
                    RelayState.Text = "OFF"
                End If

                'Input State found at index 94
                If array1(94) = "1" Then
                    inputState.Text = "ON"
                Else
                    inputState.Text = "OFF"
                End If

            End If

            'Close the connection
            tcpClient.Close()

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        inputState.Text = "Error"
        RelayState.Text = "Error"
        'Disable the timer
        TimerRelayRefresh.Enabled = False
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub sendRequest(ByVal val As String)

    Dim tcpClient As New TcpClient()
    Dim port As Integer

    Try
        'Disable the timer
        TimerRelayRefresh.Enabled = False

        port = Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text)
        tcpClient.Connect(txt_IPAddress.Text, port)

        If tcpClient.Connected Then
            MsgBox("connection successful")


            'Create a network stream object
            Dim netStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()

            'If we can read and write to the stream then do so
            If netStream.CanWrite And netStream.CanRead Then

                'Send the on command to webrelay
                Dim sendBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET /state.xml?relayState=1 HTTP/1.1<CR><LF>" & vbCrLf & "Authorization: Basic bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ==<CR><LF><CR><LF>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
                netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

                'Get the response from webrelay
                Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
                netStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))

                'Parse the response and update the webrelay state and input text boxes
                Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)


                'Parse out the relay state and input state
                Dim array1 As Char() = returndata.ToCharArray()


                'Relay State found at index 66
                If array1(66) = "1" Then
                    RelayState.Text = "ON"

                Else
                    RelayState.Text = "OFF"
                End If

                'Input State found at index 94
                If array1(94) = "1" Then
                    inputState.Text = "ON"
                End If
            Else
                    inputState.Text = "OFF"
                End If

            End If


        'Enable the timer
        TimerRelayRefresh.Enabled = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        inputState.Text = "Error"
        RelayState.Text = "Error"
        'Disable the timer
        TimerRelayRefresh.Enabled = False
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub btn_ControlsX317_On_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_ControlsX317_On.Click
    sendRequest("1")
End Sub

Private Sub btn_ControlsX317_Off_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_ControlsX317_Off.Click
    sendRequest("0")
End Sub

Private Sub btn_ControlsX317_PULSE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_ControlsX317_PULSE.Click
    sendRequest("2")
End Sub

'End Conetion
'_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

End Class

Comment: Where's your question??

Comment: my question is! how to control analog output and why when I pressed the button btn_ControlsX317_On_Click shows me OFF.

Comment: Okay, you have to explain your code more. Remember that no one here knows how your code works, or what you're trying to do. -- For starters, what do you mean by "analog output"? Secondly, I don't see the structure in this. I have no idea what the received data is nor how it is structured. You seem to know that index 66 or 94 is either 1 or 0. -- There's also a problem with your method: you think all `tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize` amount of bytes is received in a single `NetworkStream.Read()` call, but it isn't.

Comment: _(Comment too long, had to split it up in two)_ `Read()` reads _at the most_ as many bytes as you request, but it only reads what's available at that time. The return value of `Read()` indicates how many bytes it has received. You should check that and keep calling `Read()` until you've read as much as you need.

Comment: this is the first time you have to write visual baisik program in place it control program in place for web relay. I tried here to do my code from http://www.controlbyweb.com/support/tutorials/basic-script-tutorial.html . If you have an idea how I set 4 outputs it web relay with different voltage which is determined by the text box with a button set. But when pressed button ON shows me that web relay is OFF and must be ON!

Comment: Okay, the link didn't shed much light... But as I understand it you're receiving an XML string. Could you post an example of that? And if that's the case you should rather look into XML parsing instead of just expecting the values to be on index 66 and 94. -- I also found a Visual Basic example on the website you linked me to (be aware that it might be for older versions of VB, prior to VB.NET): http://www.controlbyweb.com/webrelay/WebrelayVB.zip

Comment: [How to: Parse XML with XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: I've never worked with web relays, and since I don't have one I cannot test the code properly either. Can you write the `returnData` variable into a file or a multiline text box, then copy-paste the text and post in your question? It would show the data structure, which is what I need.

Comment: just.write example as you think it will look the code. I have a fixed IP and you can test it. Here are examples Public Property MyValue As String
        Get
            Return _myValue
        End Get
        Set(txt_S1_AnalogOutput As String)
            _myValue = txt_S1_AnalogOutput
        End Set
    End Property

Comment: I don't get what I'm supposed to do with the code of a normal property. Yet again, I have never worked with web relays, and my schedule is full, so even if you are willing to pay me I'm afraid I don't have the time to help you. You are better of finding someone who knows about this, maybe contact the company that made this relay? Either way, the last way I might be able help you is if I can get a sample of the `returnData` variable. That way I could perhaps fix your problem with it reporting `OFF` instead of `ON`.

Comment: OK! thank you anyway. if you have time and you have an idea sent me. even if only a few lines of code. thank you again

Comment: As I don't understand what we're working with here, I'm afraid I can't do much. But does this mean I cannot get a piece of sample data from the `returnData` variable? Because that's the only thing I might be able to help you with right now.